# template type deduction even with empty list

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I was reading on cppreference that :

> Class template argument deduction is only performed if no template
>   argument list is present. If a template argument list is specified,
>   deduction does not take place.

with followed examples :

```
std::tuple t1(1, 2, 3);              // OK: deduction
std::tuple<int,int,int> t2(1, 2, 3); // OK: all arguments are provided
std::tuple<int> t4(1, 2, 3);         // Error
```

So far, what I understood is :

- when I give no template list, the temaplte argument will take places (like 1st example of tuple)
- When I give empty or not all argument list, there will be error.

So in my example below :

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max(T1 a, T2 b) -> typename std::decay<decltype(true? a:b)>::type
{
   return  b < a ? a : b;
}

auto c = ::max('c', 7.2); //<<< Works as template deduction took place
auto d = ::max<int>('c', 7.2);  //<<<< WOrks !!! Why
```

So for the last line why did it work even I just provided one template list (T1) not both ? I was expecting error !!

Comment: Class template argument dedication should not be projected unto function template argument deduction. There are some differences, by design. And learning by tinkering may be counter-productive.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I have no other way to learn other than trying to tinker examples and figure out what the prob is. If there is any other way I ll pleased to her.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @StoryTeller : In fact I landed over here coz I am reading C++ Templates: The Complete Guide and I still in the basics Chapter :D

Comment: While the community here stands by those books, it's usually best to read them to completion first. They often introduce things as they go along so as to not overwhelm (tinkering does overwhelm, C++ is a beast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Class template argument deduction is only performed if no template argument list is present. If a template argument list is specified, deduction does not take place

This is about deduction guides for classes, a new C++17 feature.

Before C++17 was also an error

```
std::tuple t1(1, 2, 3);
```

because before C++17 was necessary explicit **all** template parameter for classes.

> So in my example below :

Your example is about deduction for template **functions**.

A completely different thing.

For functions, you can explicit also some template parameters, non necessarily all of they.

Comment: @mmax66: I noticed that after posting the question so I m trying to chnage the function intoa  functor and test That. 

and for your last point, for functions is possible to provide partial list params ?

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd - "for functions is possible to provide partial list params ? " - It's a complicated argument and there are case that I don't understand completely; you should propose a question with some examples.